Ag-grid: How to copy value from DETAIL master grid?
How can I copy detail grid value in ag-grid-angular?
I know that it's possible to copy cell value of master grid. I define:
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
...getContextMenuItems: this.getContextMenuItems
} 
getContextMenuItems(params: GetContextMenuItemsParams): (string | MenuItemDef)[] {
  return ["copy", "export"];
}

This actually works.
But I'm using enterprise MASTER grid feature, so when I expand row I can see usual HTML table inside detail grid. But I cannot copy value inside it.
If I click area inside detail grid with right mouse click, then choose "Copy", I copy the value of ID cell, which is basically expanded:
enter image description here
So in above example, I'll copy "WV-000417595"
Please help, is there any options how can I implement it?
